# asp.net mvc 4 Send form from site to email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have feedback form on my mvc site, it looks like

[image]

and I  need to send my form to email.

I created model for my form

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace ComponentTrading.Web.Models
 {
public class FeedbackForm
    {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Email { get; set; } 
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created view for my form Contacts.cshtml

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Contacts", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contact-form" }))
{
<fieldset>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @Value = Name })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @Value = "E-mail" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @Value = Phone })
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "img-shadow" })
    <input class="form-button" data-type="reset" value="Clear" />
    <input class="form-button" data-type="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
</fieldset>     
}
```

And I wrote this code at my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contacts()
    {
        FeedbackForm temp = new FeedbackForm();
        temp.Message = @Resources.Global.Contacts_Form_Message_Field;
        return View(temp);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contacts(FeedbackForm Model)
    {
        string Text = "<html> <head> </head>" +
        " <body style= \" font-size:12px; font-family: Arial\">"+
        Model.Message+
        "</body></html>";

        SendEmail("tayna-anita@mail.ru", Text);
        FeedbackForm tempForm = new FeedbackForm();
        return View(tempForm);
    }


    public static bool SendEmail(string SentTo, string Text)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("Test@mail.ru");
        msg.To.Add(SentTo);
        msg.Subject = "Password";
        msg.Body = Text;
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);



        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("TestLogin", "TestPassword");
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        //client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I dont have any errors at my code,
but when I push Send button, I dont get email and my form doesnt become clear.

I used Fiddler Web Debugger and I got for Send-button click
[image]

As I see, it means all right, so I cant undersnand what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copy-pasted your code and got it to work, with some small modifications:

1. I did not set the `Credentials` property
2. I modified the template to remove the @Value attribute:

   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)

These are the only changes I made and I got your application to work. This leads me to believe that there must be something wrong in your SMTP client's configuration. Can you examine the exception that is thrown by `client.Send(msg);`? I expect it will say something about invalid network credentials or something like that.

Comment: I received your message on email. Tell me please, how did you change Smtp settings?

Comment: @Heidel I removed the Credentials property and replaced the smtp client's address to my private smtp server.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

To

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
// breakpoint here, inspect ex
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: In your catch, try returning ex.Message like this: "return Content(ex.Message);"