# Sending an automatic email in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I'm attempting to send the results of a form in email form to a set destination. I've given this a number of attempts myself and failed miserably. So I found a question that was asking the same and adapted the answer to fit my solution... I think..

The Answer I've been following is from [**asp.net mvc 4 Send form from site to email**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665795/asp-net-mvc-4-send-form-from-site-to-email)

When I click the submit button on my form, it retrieves the data no problem. The issue is in sending the email.

My code currently looks like this...

Model:

```
namespace Domain.Models
{
    public class Event
    {

        public int? ArrangerId { get; set; }
        public Arranger Arranger { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It carries on like that. It quite a long list but it's all the same.

View:

```
@model Domain.Models.Event
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "EventSubmission"))
{
    <h3>Your contact details</h3>

    <h5>Name</h5>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Arranger.Contact_Name);
    <br />
    <h5>Email address</h5>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Arranger.Contact_Phone);
    <br/>
    <h5>Phone number</h5>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Arranger.Contact_Email);
    ......
}
```

Again, carries on in the same way

Controller:

```
namespace EventsMap.Controllers
{
    public class EventSubmissionController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new Event());
        }



        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Submit()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(Event ev)
        {
            string Text = "<html> <head> </head>" +
            " <body style= \" font-size:12px; font-family: Arial\">" +
            ev.Location.Postcode +
            "</body></html>";

            SendEmail("TestEmail@gmail.com", Text);
            Event tempForm = new Event();
            return View(tempForm);
        }


        public static bool SendEmail(string SentTo, string Text)
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

            msg.From = new MailAddress("TestEmail@gmail.com");
            msg.To.Add(SentTo);
            msg.Subject = "subject";
            msg.Body = Text;
            msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);



            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            //client.EnableSsl = true;

            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

> The exception that I get back is "Failure sending mail", "Unable to
>   connect to the remote server", "An attempt was made to access a socket
>   in a way forbidden by its access permissions 64.233.166.109:587"

So clearly it is something wrong with the `smtp` business but other than that i'm lost.

Comment: Did you [google the exception](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=An+attempt+was+made+to+access+a+socket+in+a+way+forbidden+by+its+access+permissions&oq=An+attempt+was+made+to+access+a+socket+in+a+way+forbidden+by+its+access+permissions&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.207j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)? There are quite a few results, in particular this: "A socket error 10013 can be caused by the antivirus or firewall software. Basically, a needed socket connection is being denied. Socket error 10013 is a message which implies that a port is blocked and/or unreachable."

Comment: Set `EnableSsl = true` when using GMail SMTP provider, and provide `NetworkCredential` (GMail username and password) to `SmtpClient` instance. If the problem still persist, check your server's antivirus/firewall configuration or third party access filters, probably it silently blocking IIS worker process from accessing SMTP socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

Soooo.... the answer was actually pretty simple. Google was preventing me from using the account from "Less secure apps". there is an option within gmail that you can turn on to allow access. Thanks for the help anyway. It did lead me towards the answer :)